# removing extention from URL doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using **htaccess** below to remove **.php** from URL but it won't work.

`http://www.me.com/index.php` should read `http://www.me.com/index`

Any reason why?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I looked at these examples too but no luck:

[1](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/) - [2](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/247708/remove-.php-from-urls-wth-.htaccess-file) - [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/htaccess-to-remove-php-extension-godaddy)

Comment: You misunderstood the use case. It rewrites **incoming** URLs. It does not adapt your pages. (There's a mod_rewrite workaround to accomplish it, or `mod_substitute` for rewrting pages on your behalf. But both off-topic..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your missing the point - it doesnt change/rewrite the URL - it adds `.php` to the URL you request, so when you request `http://www.example.com/index` it checks the requested filename is not a directory (`!-d`) and then checks a valid PHP file exists (`-f`). Then rewrites the request (not the URL) to request the `index.php` file.

From the [documentation for `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) this is the description

> Provides a rule-based rewriting engine to rewrite requested URLs on the fly

Comment: @JasonMcCreary i created the comment - then thought ... what the heck - might as well turn it into an answer - might be helpful to others - the comment has since been removed :-)

Comment: When I look for "removing extention from URL... " like words in search engines, most of them says the code above works fine to remove extension html, php... I wonder why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MadMax You request `/index` and it doesnt show `/index.php` ? do you get a 404 ?

Comment: No error at all. All pages appear with `.php` part at the end. Also my actual php files are in same place with `htaccess` file. All in main root folder.

Comment: @MadMax are you user `mod_rewrite` is enabled ? have you changed `href`s ? for example requesting `/about` instead of `/about.php` ?

Comment: I though calling `index.php` would automatically rewrites to `index`. Anyway, I now removed extensions from `href`. It works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used this `.htaccess`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

that renames the three parameters

- 1st is Page
- 2nd is s
- 3rd is o

It is to avoid the usage of `?` and `&` in my URLs and then i call my pages like this

```
http://testsite/page/s/o
```

If you just do `print_r($_REQUEST)` it will give you this

```
Array(
page => page
s    => s
o    => o
)
```

**To avoid extensions**, I user the following mechanism

```
$file = $_REQUEST['page'] . ".php";
if (file_exists('inc/' . $file)) {
    include('inc/' . $file);
}
```

Hope it will work for you as well